# Checkbox inside React Router Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am building a list of entities in React. Each entity is wrapped in a link and redirects to a page. Inside each entity's link there's a checkbox and a button that opens a dropdown:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <Link to={url}>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </label>
      <h3>Entity name</h3>
      <time datetime="">2019-09-21</time>
      <button type="button">Dropdown</button>
    </Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If a user clicks the checkbox OR dropdown button, it should not redirect to the page but rather do another action.

**Question 1:** Is this feasable with an anchor tag like in the example? I don't want to use an `onClick` handler.

**Question 2:** The checkbox inside the `Link` can not be toggled, [see this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-forest-4udpv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Why is that?

Comment: Why would you wrap checkbox inside an anchor tag?

Comment: Because the whole area should be a link to the entity page, with the exception of the checkbox which should rather select it. Similar to Gmails interface.

Comment: So why not wrap the checkbox in a label instead and wrap the rest in the anchor tag?

Comment: That's not how the design specification is :(
I know it's stupid, but due to padding and spacing the link should wrap the entire checkbox and dropdown

Answer (score 0):

From that example link moving the Link to only around the text looks exactly the same but gives you what you want.

```
      <label style={{ display: "block" }}>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <Link to="/">Inside the link</Link>
      </label>
```

Having a checkbox inside a checkable area doesn't sound like a great user experience - the user might expect the outer area to check the box

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I used `onClick`, React `state`, and `stopPropogation` that it achieved the effect you described.

```
<Link>
  <input
    checked={this.state.checked}
    type="checkbox"
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
    }}
  />
</Link>
```